# dell optiplex 755 power button flashing orange

Tags: power, dell-optiplex

i have a Dell Optiplex 755 when i turn it on i just get a flashing orange light from the power button.

I know there is power going to the motherboard as there is an orange light that is on.

i have tried a power flush and changed the power supply and flushed the cmos but it still flashes orange and wont boot up the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Dell's Optiplex series, if the power button is flashing amber, that indicates a power supply problem.  However, you said you replaced the power supply...  If you are sure the power supply you put in was good, then unfortunately your motherboard is probably dead.

Comment: thanks. I thought might be motherboard but was hoping it wouldn't be